# Is there anyway to get schema from the parquet files being queried?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So, I have parquet files separated by folder with date in it, something like

```
root_folder
  |_date=20210101
     |_ file_A.parquet 
  |_date=20210102
     |_ file_B.parquet
```

file_A has 2 column `X,Y`, file_B has 3 column `X,Y,Z`

but when i query using sparksession on the date 20210102, it's using schema from the topmost folder that is 20210101 and when i tried querying column `Z` it doesn't exist.
I've tried using `mergeSchema=true` option, but it doesn't fit my use case because I need to treat those with column `Z` differently, and i'm checking if there's column `Z` using `DataFrame.columns`.

Is there any workaround for this? I need to get schema from the one i query only.

Comment: The question isn't all that clear, but if you read the parquet directly, it'll infer the schema just for that one.  So something like `spark.read.parquet("basePath/_date=20210102")` would give you a different schema than `spark.read.parquet("basePath/_date=20210101")`

Comment: ah, i forgot to mention that i query by range of date, like this. `sparkSession.read.parquet(s"$source/$domain").filter($"date" >= startDate && $"date" <= endDate)`. if i make another read session for only 1 date, that is the `startDate`, will the overhead cost be big?

Comment: No, it won't be too big.  Given how this needs to work, I would recommend loading each day and then treating that day as necessary.  There are functions to determine the specific dates between those ranges.  I.e. this does it https://github.com/kanielc/jarvis-utils/blob/d95442ffad1d61d9269e87228e0911508784655f/src/main/scala/com/jarvis/utils/DateTimeUtils.scala#L40

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If computational cost is not a concern, you can solve this problem by reading the entire dataset into spark, filter to the date you are looking for, and then drop the column if is entirely null.

This performs a pass over the data just to figure out if the column should be dropped, which is not great. Luckily `.where` and `.count` parallelize pretty well so you have enough compute it might be okay.

```scala
val base = spark.read
  .option("mergeSchema", true)
  .parquet("root_folder/")
  .where(col("date") === "20210101")

val df = if (base.where(col("Z").isNotNull).count > 0) base.drop("Z") else base

df.schema // Should only have X, Y
```

If you want to generalize this into a function that drops all empty columns, you can compute the `.isNotNull` count for all columns in 1 pass.

Comment: unfortunately yes, computational cost is a concern since i'm not running it in my own machine. but thank you for your answer.